# matching the actual string "%0" with regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match the sub-string `CONTENT=%0` using regular expressions. I have been trying for quite some time and nothing seems to work! Any ideas?

Comment: Are u serious! That the case really needs regex at all!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use regex for this simple kind of task, but... you can if you want to... use regex pattern

```
CONTENT=%0
```

---

#### PHP code:

```
$pattern = '/CONTENT=%0/';
$s = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $s);
```

See **[this demo](http://ideone.com/ZQ3GjP)**.

Comment: ok let me be clearer: i wanna do this
$macro = ereg_replace("CONTENT=%0","CONTENT=#2",$macro);

Comment: @MikaëlLevy - The function `ereg_replace` has been **deprecated**.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me: `/CONTENT=%0/`